# Can you turn PHP text into a variable?

Tags: php

I was wondering if it was possible to dynamically create variables like so:

```
$sender = $email = $number = $message = "";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if isset & !empty //loosely typed
    $+key = $value // can something like this be done?
}
```

if so how?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Many thanks, interesting.

Comment: np. Note that I am 99.999% sure you actually are looking for `array`s instead.

Comment: I feel like I need to down vote every answer here for teaching OP to do what is essentially register globals.

Comment: Expand a little Jonathan if you dont mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does have [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but you don't need that here.  I think a simple associative array or object will work just fine for you.

```
$data = array(
  'sender' => 'Someone',
  'email' => 'test@example.com',
  'number' => 12345,
  'message' => 'some message'
);

echo $data['sender']; // Someone
```

Comment: "you don't need that here" can pretty much be replaced with "you don't need that **ever**" - I have yet to see a piece of code using variables variables which would not be better with an associative array.

Comment: while I agree that an array is better here, if OP is using $_POST as in their example, it already is in an array.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Agreed, if that is the format needed.  My read was that he needed to change the structure a bit, but that is a good point depending on his intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. But I wouldn't do it unless you completely trust the data and if its POST data then access it like `$_POST['key']`

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if isset & !empty //loosely typed
    ${$key} = $value // can something like this be done?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a PHP function called `extract` which does what you are looking for.

https://www.php.net/extract

Comment: That doesn't take into account empty values though.

Comment: Extract is a nasty function and should NEVER be used.